# How to send data to a PHP file and point to what it returns through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, virtualhost

I have set up my Virtual Host in a way that it points all subdomains to their respective directories. For example, `ok.domain.com` points to `domain.com/ok`.

`ok.domain.com/page` points to `domain.com/ok/page`.

However, I want users to be able to have their own custom domains point to their directories.

I have a PHP file containing **keys** that point a user's custom domain to whichever directory belongs to them.

```
"someusersite.com"=>"bob",
"anotheruserdomain.co"=>"test"
```

Is there a **rewrite rule** I could use that sends the URL the user is on to this PHP file and then points to whatever it returns.

So if the user is on `someusersite.com`, this domain should be sent to the PHP file which in turn will echo out the value `bob`. Now the user should be pointed to `bob`.

Each of these custom domains will have `A Records` put in place.

I have tried letting users point their domain to their subdomain via a **CNAME** record but that doesn't work - it just points to the root site.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of keeping this mapping in a php code, you can keep this mapping in a text file and use `RewriteMap` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect all to index.php htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Redirect all access from a folder to a PHP file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^doc\/(.*)\.html$ download.php?r=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this retrieves the value of a PHP file and points to whatever value it retrieves. It should send a URL to the PHP file, that PHP file will then return a domain to point to

Comment: i providede a way through which you can do that. try using it else provide the code snippet then we can help you out